# Why is skrollr preventing scrolling on ipad?

Tags: ipad, parallax, skrollr

I'm trying to create a simple parallax animation with [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr): my site is working well on Chrome/Mac but I'm seeing unusual behaviour on the ipad..

On ipad (testing on the IOS simulator),

- the main body of the page doesn't skroll at all (or may scroll in the background, underneath the animated div?)
- the animated background position (origami pattern) scrolls in the opposite direction (down is up) within the bounds defined in `data-start` / `data-top-bottom`

On desktop, the effect I can simulate the effect if I hack the `div#hero` to be `position: fixed;` in chrome dev tools.

- The [skrollr examples](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/tree/master/examples) work as expected in the IOS simulator.
- I have `<div id="skrollr-body"></div>` just before the closing `</body>` tag

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I have <div id="skrollr-body"></div> just before the closing </body> tag" **why?**

Comment: Hi @Prinzhorn! "Include an element on your page with the id skrollr-body." I didn't look at the example: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/bg_constant_speed_less.html closely enough - I've wrapped the entire page in #skrollr-body and it works!! Tx! Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just naively added an empty `#skrollr-body` element. The documentation says

> Starting with skrollr 0.6.0 there's just one thing you need to do: Include an element on your page with the id skrollr-body. That's the element we move in order to fake scrolling.

If that's the element we move for fake scrolling, then all your elements need to be inside of it (unless they're fixed positioned).

> The only case were you don't need a #skrollr-body is when using position:fixed exlusively. In fact the skrollr website doesn't include a #skrollr-body element. If you need both fixed and non-fixed (i.e. static) elements, put the static ones inside the #skrollr-body element.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#what-you-need-in-order-to-support-mobile-browsers

Comment: fair call, thanks - late night and crossed wires; case closed.

Answer (score 11):

So in other words, simply add a `<div id="skrollr-body">` tag right after the opening `<body>` tag, and close this division by adding a `</div>` right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. The result was that I was unable to scroll the full height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

adding a div wrapper with skrollr-body id did absolutely nothing for, scroll just doesn't work on mobile