# My website scroll is disabled with jQuery (rare)

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I'm using bootstrap 3 on my website and jQuery.
On mobile, my responsive design doesn't scroll down.

If I remove the jquery plugin this works perfectly. I tried to use different jquery plugins from CDN's but the result is the same in any case...

The JS console isn't throwing errors.

Website: http://beta.llopgestio.cat/

Thanks!

**Solved question here: [Skrollr problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923605/why-is-skrollr-preventing-scolling-on-ipad)**

Comment: Can you give us a link maybe in order to try ?

Comment: yes sure! http://beta.llopgestio.cat/

Comment: So, have you experimented to see which plugin is the problematic one?

Comment: Finally the problematic plugin was skrollr, thanks!